# python argparse with dependencies

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a script which has 2 arguments which are mutually exclusive, and an option that only makes sense with one of those arguments. I'm trying to set up argparse to fail if you call it with the argument that makes no sense.

To be clear:

`-m -f` makes sense

`-s` makes sense

`-s -f` should throw errors

no arguments are fine.

The code I have is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Lookup servers by ip address from host file')
parser.add_argument('host', nargs=1,
            help="ip address to lookup")
main_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mysql_group = main_group.add_argument_group()
main_group.add_argument("-s", "--ssh", dest='ssh', action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help='Connect to this machine via ssh, instead of printing hostname')
mysql_group.add_argument("-m", "--mysql", dest='mysql', action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help='Start a mysql tunnel to the host, instead of printing hostname')
mysql_group.add_argument("-f", "--firefox", dest='firefox', action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help='Start a firefox session to the remotemyadmin instance')
```

Which doesn't work, as it spits out

```
 usage: whichboom [-h] [-s] [-m] [-f] host
```

rather than what I'd expect:

```
 usage: whichboom [-h] [-s | [-h] [-s]] host
```

or somesuch.

```
 whichboom -s -f -m 116
```

also doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have the argument groups mixed up. In your code, you only assign one option to the mutually exclusive group. I think what you want is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Lookup servers by ip address from host file')
parser.add_argument('host', nargs=1,
            help="ip address to lookup")
main_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mysql_group = main_group.add_argument_group()
main_group.add_argument("-s", "--ssh", dest='ssh', action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help='Connect to this machine via ssh, instead of printing hostname')
mysql_group.add_argument("-m", "--mysql", dest='mysql', action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help='Start a mysql tunnel to the host, instead of printing hostname')
main_group.add_argument("-f", "--firefox", dest='firefox', action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help='Start a firefox session to the remotemyadmin instance')
```

You could just skip the whole mutually exclusive group thing and add something like this:

```
usage = 'whichboom [-h] [-s | [-h] [-s]] host'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description, usage)
options, args = parser.parse_args()
if options.ssh and options.firefox:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: This is a functional workaround. I'll set it up to bomb out with invalid options, but I feel it's a kludge. If I can't get it sorted this morning I'll go hassle the developers, it may be a bug.

Comment: I add the mysql group, and one further option to the mutually_exclusive_group. I suppose I was expecting the option to exclude the other group, but that's not how it's working. I wound up going with your other solution.

Comment: `argument group` and `mutually exclusive group` have very different purposes, and cannot be meaningfully nested.  `argument_group` doesn't mean `any of the above`.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `usage` argument when creating the parser:

```
usage = "usage: whichboom [-h] [-s | [-h] [-s]] host"
description = "Lookup servers by ip address from host file"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description, usage=usage)
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#usage

Comment: This at best fixes the command line printing, it doesn't unbreak the functionality (program accepts an invalid argument set) and means I have to maintain that line by hand.. the usage line is the least of my concerns, I included it mainly in case it would help someone understand what's happening.