# Parsing into python script from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, argparse

I am using argparse module to pass the argument to the python script from the command line, something like this:

`python.py`

```
import argparse

if__name__=="__main__"
      parser.add_argument("--set", help="Usage example --set xyz.pqr=1", 
      action="append")
```

Now if I use `python3 python.py --set xyz.pqr`
it is still  getting parsed into the script. I want this not to parse and display an Error msg: Invalid command, missing '=' sign in the command.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: You want to define the argument such that it requires a value; look in particular for the `type` keyword. This is covered rather well in the documentation. I can't find an obvious duplicate, but see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134549/python-argparse-requiring-option-depending-on-the-defined-flags

Comment: what should I put in type=' <>', such that it checks the presence of '=' sign and then proceeds accordingly?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You basically need to implement your own type. It's not very complicated, but I'm wondering if there would not be a better way to express this (say one option to set `--xyzpqr 1` etc)

Comment: You need to write a small function that takes the string, and checks for that desired character. If missing raise a `ValueError` (or `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`).  And return an accepted string.  Basically the same as if you were testing it after parsing.